# Package used for function "BoostFit"?

Tags: r, function, package

I have been attempting to follow this tutorial:

http://edureka.co/blog/data-science-projects

I have reached the following line, but it fails with an error:

```
confusionMatrix (TrainSet$incomelevel, predict (boostFit, TrainSet))
```

> Error in predict(boostFit, TrainSet) : object 'boostFit' not found

What is the package that should be used in order to use the function "boost Fit"??

I thought I had created it with a previous line in the code:

```
boostFit = train(incomelevel ~ age + workclass + education + educationnum +
                 maritalstatus + occupation + relationship + race + capitalgain +
                 capitalloss + hoursperweek + nativecountry,
                 trControl = trCtrl, method = "gbm", data = TrainSet,
                 verbose = FALSE)
```

Does this mean I need to install a package for function `boostFit`, and if yes then what is the package name??

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Right now you aren't using `boostFit` as a function, it's just a variable name. Did you create a variable with that name? If not, why is that included in the `predict()`?

Comment: I found this code on this site------------- https://www.edureka.co/blog/data-science-projects/           -----------       I don't know whats wrong with this code, but it's showing this error. It'd be very helpful if anyone could find the solution to this.

Comment: and yes, th3e variable with that name was created-----  
boostFit = train (incomelevel ~ age + workclass + education + educationnum +
                    maritalstatus + occupation + relationship +
                    race + capitalgain + capitalloss + hoursperweek +
                    nativecountry, trControl = trCtrl,
                  method = "gbm", data = TrainSet, verbose = FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but once I loaded the CARET package it worked well.